# is there any way to edit an inout port without using assign?

Tags: verilog

My goal is to implement a module that has an inout port, the description of this module is behavioral, to implement this module, my teacher said, I should not use the assign command.

So is there any way to edit an inout port without using assign?

This is my code :

```
module DRAM(addr,rw,data);

parameter N=8;
parameter M=8;


input rw;
input [N-1:0] addr;
inout [M-1:0] data;


reg [M-1:0] data;
reg [M-1:0] loc_data [512:0];


always @(*)
 begin

 if(rw)
  begin
   loc_data[addr]=data;
  end
 else if(!rw) 
 begin
  data=loc_data[addr]; //this is my problem.

 end 
 else
 begin
 end
end

endmodule
```

Comment: It depends on what your teacher's definition of *behavioral description* means.

Comment: @dave_59 He did not say anything specific, his behavioral description is provided from Samir Palnitkar's book, just point it out and do not use the assign command. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: It is not possible to write into an inout port  without continuous assignment.  Check with you r teacher what he/she meant.

Comment: @Serge, not true. You can use `bufif` and MOS primitives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply need to avoid the `assign` keyword, you can use a wire declaration assignment instead.

```
module DRAM#(parameter N=8,M=8) (
    input         rw,
    input [N-1:0] addr,
    inout [M-1:0] .data(data_w)
);

reg  [M-1:0] data_r;
wire [M-1:0] data_w = rw ? {M{1'bz}} : data_r;
reg  [M-1:0] loc_data [512:0];

always @(*)
 if(rw)
   loc_data[addr]=data_w;
 else if(!rw) 
  data_r=loc_data[addr];
 
endmodule
```

Comment: just a comment: the declaration assignment only removes the keyword, but underneath is the same continuous assignment.

Comment: @Serge This is why I hate these kinds of questions https://jokes.fandom.com/wiki/Lost_Helicopter_Pilot

Comment: :-) Right, it is very similar :-).